# My own pod library does not import in project

Tags: cocoapods, swift5, xcode12

Trying to create my own library

PodSpec: [podspec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocSl9.png)

PodFile: [podFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9tdT.png)

Pod lib lint: [pod lib lint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD50A.png)

Import: [import library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjeXl.png)

I call pod install and the dependency is installed but i can't do import

enter image description here

if you just download the zip archive with the library and drop it into the project, then everything works

Please tell me how to fix this problem

Comment: I can not find file .framework, I have 2 files but I need skyline.framework

Comment: while when I updat Podfile, dependency manager say, what he download all dependencies

Comment: The problem is that the dependency manager cannot download apparently the .framework file itself

Comment: Please post code, not pictures of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your podspec, make sure to include files recursively:

```rb
spec.source_files  = 'Skyline/**/*.{h,m,swift}'
```

Comment: spec.exclude_files remove?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have the included suffixes anyway.

Comment: tell me how you install the latest version of the library, pod update does not download the latest version of the library

Comment: 1) pod repo update

2) pod deintegrate

3) pod install

// I tried to call such a sequence of commands, but all without success

Comment: Either use local pod `pod 'Skyline', :path => '~/some/local/dir'` or download the latest from github `pod 'Skyline', :git => 'https://github.com/VYR3X/Skyline'`